# How does the viewport coordinate system work in svg?

Tags: svg

I am trying to understand how the coordinate systems works in `svg`.

In the following HTML, I am unable to understand why the images enlarge if I don't specify viewport.

There seems to be a default size of `viewport` if I don't specify any value. What is it?

```
<!-- what is the default dimension of a viewport? -->
<p> no viewport or view box. viewport seem to have a default size. anything outside is clipped</p>
<svg style="border-style: dotted">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
</svg>

<p> no viewport or view box. viewport seem to have a default size. anything outside is clipped</p>
<svg style="border-style: dotted">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="1500" ry="1500"></ellipse>
</svg>

<p>viewport but no viewbox. Only what is in viewport is visible. Same as default viewport value case but we are specifying the dimensions of viewport here</p>
<svg width="50" height="50" style="border-style: dotted">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
</svg>

<p>viewport but no viewbox. Only what is in viewport is visible.  Same as default viewport value case but we are specifying the dimensions of viewport here</p>
<svg width="50" height="50" style="border-style: dotted">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="1500" ry="1500"></ellipse>
</svg>
<!-- why this is large?-->
<p>viewbox but no viewport. Viewport takes same space as viewbox</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="border-style: dotted">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
</svg>
<!-- why this is large?-->
<p>viewbox but no viewport. Viewport takes same space as viewbox</p>
<svg viewBox="20 20 100 100" style="border-style: dotted">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
</svg>

<p>viewport and viewbox. Value of viewport determines what would be visible</p>
<svg width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="border-style: dotted">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
</svg>
```

Comment: The default size (of all replaced elements) is 300 x 150

Comment: I tried giving the `viewbox` dimension `0 0 300 150` the `viewport` border is bigger than usual. `<svg viewBox="0 0 300 150" style="border-style: dotted">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
</svg>` Why is that? Shouldn't the border get smaller?

Comment: if you set a viewBox you mandate a fixed aspect ratio by default

Comment: Thanks. makes sense. Is there a way not to preserve the aspect ratio. I just want to see the behavior. I tried adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to `<svg>` but it didn't work. Also, happy to accept your answer if you could convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: preserveAspectRatio="none" should work.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. I created an html file with content `<svg viewBox="0 0 300 150" style="border-style: dotted" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
</svg>` but I see the border much bigger than the ellipse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172052/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-manu-chadha).